# Python throws a 'not defined' error at a declared function

Tags: python, binary-search

I wrote the following code. The function that I am calling is declared at the top:

```
class Solution:
    
    def search_val(self, arr, low, high, x):
        
        high = len(arr)
        low = 0
        
        if high >= low:
            
            mid = (high + low) // 2
            
            if arr[mid] == x:
                print('Target is in the middle', mid)
            
            elif arr[mid] > x:
                print(search_val(self, arr, low, mid - 1, x))
            
            else:
                print(search_val(self, arr, mid + 1, high, x))
        
        else:
            print('-1')

    def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        
        high = len(nums)
        low = 0
        
        print(self.search_val(nums, low, high, target))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'search_val' is not defined
    print(search_val(nums, low, high, target))
Line 29 in searchInsert (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().searchInsert(param_1, param_2)
Line 54 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 65 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you need to add `self` in front of calls to search_val  `print(self.search_val(nums, low, high, target))`

Comment: Do `self.search_val(...)`

Comment: you really should read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) before just writing class definitions guessing at how they work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`search_val` is not a global function.  It is a member of the class, even though it's not using `self`.

If you need to have this as a member of the class, then you need to change the header to:

```
    def search_val(self, arr, low, high, x):
```

and you need to call it as:

```
        print(self.search_val(nums, low, high, target))`
```

If this is for a contest, they usually want you to RETURN the value, rather than PRINT the value.

Comment: Thanks Tim but see my updated answer. I'm still getting the same error..

Comment: You have two calls to `search_val(self,...`.  Follow the pattern.  You need `self.search_val(...`